# XmlSerializer Mixed Content Deserialization

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer, mixed

How do I setup my class to deserialize the following mixed content xml?

```
<employee>
  <name>John Doe</name>
  <remark>He is a <match>tall</match> and handsome man</remark>
</employee>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("match")]
> public match[] match {
>   get {
>     return this._match;
>   }
>   set {
>     this._match = value;
>   }
> }
>
> /// 
> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
> public string[] Text {
>   get {
>     return this.textField;
>   }
>   set {
>     this.textField = value;
>   }
> }

Comment: But here you are missing the order of content, You are splitting text and match to different arrays.